# Codeiginiter CRUD with tabs

Tags: php, codeigniter, tabs

I'm building a CRUD application with tabs using **Codeigniter** framework:

**Basic Info** tab with fields:

```
name, surname, dob, email, ...
```

**Address** tab with fields:

```
unit, number, street name, ...
```

**Emergency Contact** tab with fields:

```
name, contact number, ...
```

Each tab has a different table in my database.

My problem is when I click on the **Register** button, just the **Basic Info** tab is being saved in the database.

I'm thinking that I have to use JavaScript to take all the information from the form, but I'm not sure.

Comment: We're not mind-readers :-) You'll need to edit your question and show us some code - please try to keep it to the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate the problem.  Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and specifically how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  The simpler you can make the problem, the more likely and faster you are to get help!

Comment: Don't Panic! Thank you very much to reply to my post. I got it!  I added this line $address['cleaner_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();  in my code and it works!